# How to handle searches on a list when its only loading part of the page until you scroll down

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016

Upon loading our list, only the first 50 or so items load until you start scrolling down the list and then it loads about 20-30 more items and continues adding them bit by bit until you reach the end of the list or page. This causes an issue for us when trying to search using ctrl+f.

Is there any way to force the list to fully load automatically when opening or a better way to search for a specific item then the built in browser search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using the modern list interface (please correct me if I'm wrong). 
If that's the case, there should be the search box in the left top part of the screen, below the site logo. That search box should do the filtering on all the columns of the list and show you only the results where some of the columns contain the value that you searched for.

So there is no need to load all the rows and use the browser's search functionality.

**EDIT:**
Besides the search, you also have the [Filter pane](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-the-list-and-library-filters-pane-293561ed-fb2e-4fb2-9a9f-8a21e299e323), where you can do the filtering on the columns by choosing the values from lists.

Comment: thank you!! I never realize that could be used to search within the lists as well